# Local dimension of stationary measures for iterated function systems with an expanding map

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, markov-process, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

This question was previously posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454667/local-dimension-of-stationary-measures-for-iterated-function-systems-with-an-exp).

Consider the iterated function system (IFS) $X_n$ on $I = [0,1] $generated by the functions $\Phi = \{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ and the probability vector $P = (p/2,p/2,1-p),$ where:

1. $f_1,f_2: I\to I$, where $f_1(x) = x/2$ and $f_2(x) = (1+x)/2$;
2. $f_3:I\to I$,  where:

   - $f_3(0)=0$, $f_3(1/2) = 1,$ $|f_3'|(x) > 1;$ and
   - $f_3(x) = f_3(1-x)$ for every $x\in [0,1/2].$
3. $0< 1- p<\varepsilon$.

---

Under the above conditions, it is relatively easy to show that if $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough $X_n$ admits a unique stationary measure $\mu$ on [0,1] and
$$W(\mathcal P^n \nu, \mu) \xrightarrow{n\to 0} 0,\ \text{exponentially fast}, $$
where $W(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) and
$$\mathcal P \nu = \sum_{i=1}^{3}p_i \nu(f_i^{-1}(\cdot)). $$

---

### My question:

Given $x\in \mathrm{supp}\mu$, define $$d_-(\mu,x) = \liminf_{r\to 0}\frac{\log \mu(B_r(x))}{\log r}\ \text{and}\ d_+(\mu,x) = \limsup_{r\to 0}\frac{\log \mu(B_r(x))}{\log r}. $$

In case $d_{-}(x) = d_{+}(x)$ we say that $d(x) = d_{+}(x).$

> **Quesiton:** Is it possible to show that there exists $d>0$ such that $d(x) = d$ for $\mu$-almost every $x\in [0,1]$. Or at least, to show that $d_-(x) \geq d$ for $\mu$-almost every $x\in [0,1]$.

In the literature, I can only find results that either assume that all $f_i$ functions are contracting or that the $f_i$ functions are contracting on average and have disjoint images, which is not my case. Also, I found this [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.12342), which solves the second part of my question, assuming that each $f_i$ is a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism (with its image) and some mild non-degenerated conditions (sadly, I was not able to replicate the method proposed in this paper to my example).

Any references or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but you may want to have a look at https://www.jstor.org/stable/121072

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion